# Make yylex return symbol_type instead of int

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to return symbol objects from yylex, as is shown in this documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Complete-Symbols.html

However, when I compile, I find that `return yy::parser::make_PLUS();` gets put into `int yyFlexLexer::yylex()`, so I get this error message (and many similar ones form other rules):

```
lexer.ll:22:10: error: no viable conversion from 'parser::symbol_type' (aka 'basic_symbol<yy::parser::by_type>') to 'int'
{ return yy::parser::make_PLUS(); }
```

What is the correct way to fix this?

lexer.ll

```
%{
#include "ASTNode.hpp"

// why isn't this in parser.tab.hh?
# ifndef YY_NULLPTR
#  if defined __cplusplus && 201103L <= __cplusplus
#   define YY_NULLPTR nullptr
#  else
#   define YY_NULLPTR 0
#  endif
# endif

#include "parser.tab.hh"

#define yyterminate() return yy::parser::make_END()
%}

%option nodefault c++ noyywrap

%%
"+"            { return yy::parser::make_PLUS(); }
"-"            { return yy::parser::make_MINUS(); }
... more rules ...
%%
```

parser.yy

```
%{
#include "AstNode.hpp"
#include ...

static int yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type *arg);
%}

%skeleton "lalr1.cc"

%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert

%token          END 0
%token          PLUS
%token          MINUS
%token ... many tokens ...
%type   <ASTNode *> S statement_list ...

%%

S:      statement_list
        { $$ = g_ast = (StatementList *)$1; }
    ;

... more rules ...

%%

static int yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type *arg) {
    (void)arg;
    static FlexLexer *flexLexer = new yyFlexLexer();
    return flexLexer->yylex();
}

void yy::parser::error(const std::string &msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `YY_NULLPTR` is not defined in the header, because it's not used in the header.  Bison tries to limit the number of symbols it "exports".  Why did you feel a need for it?

Comment: It's used in parser.tab.hh for me, so it wouldn't compile without it.

Comment: But it should not!  Can I get your `*.y` file somewhere and see why Bison generates broken output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare `yylex`, both in the generated scanner and in the generated parser, with the correct signature. Obviously, returning `int` is not what you want.

In the calc++ example included in the bison distribution (and described in the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Calc_002b_002b-Scanner)), you can see how to do this:

> Then comes the declaration of the scanning function. Flex expects the signature of yylex to be defined in the macro YY_DECL, and the C++ parser expects it to be declared. We can factor both as follows.

```
// Tell Flex the lexer's prototype ...
# define YY_DECL \
  yy::calcxx_parser::symbol_type yylex (calcxx_driver& driver)
// ... and declare it for the parser's sake.
YY_DECL;
```

That's just the normal way of changing the `yylex` declaration. Although the bison manual doesn't mention this, and the `.ll` suffix is arguably misleading, it is *not* using the C++ flex skeleton. It is using the C skeleton to generate a file which can be compiled with C++. As far as I can see, it is not even generating a reentrant lexer.

There is also an important option in the [`calc++.yy` file](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Calc_002b_002b-Parser):

> The driver is passed by reference to the parser and to the scanner. This provides a simple but effective pure interface, not relying on global variables.

```
// The parsing context.
%param { calcxx_driver& driver }
```

That indicates that `calcxx_driver& driver` is an argument both to the parser and to the scanner. That is, you provide it to the parser, and the parser automatically passes it through to the scanner. That matches the `yylex` prototype generated with `YY_DECL`.

You might not actually need that object in your scanner actions. I don't think that its use is mandatory, but I have hardly ever used the C++ APIs in either bison or flex, so I could well be wrong.

Comment: It is indeed not needed to have the driver in the scanner, but it's a handy way to have access to the parser, and in particular to `yyerror` to signal invalid tokens.

Comment: @akim, fair enough. I'm not a big fan of calling yyerror from the scanner, but there are good arguments both ways.

Comment: Actually I used to have the scanner use the parser's `yyerror`, but later I moved to having the driver provide the error reporting function, used by both the parser and the scanner.  `%param {driver& d}` is needed in that case too.  But now, my favorite approach in C++ is to have the scanner throw a `syntax_error`.

Comment: @akim: for those not allergic to exceptions (and not subject to coding standards which forbid them) that seems like an excellent approach, although it complicates error recovery. A more interesting case is a lexical *warning*. I'd go with the "put it in the driver" framework, which as you say requires access to the driver object. But my uncertainty was whether the generated scanner has some poorly-documented and/or unobvious context dependency. Since I never use the flex c++ api, I have no experience to guide me.

Comment: "it complicates error recovery".  Well, it depends what you call error recovery: `syntax_error` _triggers_ the error recovery of Bison's parsers, exactly like `YYERROR` would.  But `yyerror` is called first, so it's really like a syntax error that would be found by the parser itself. Wrt the scanner, yes, you do need to pay attention of possible local state (say start conditions) and restore them before throwing.  Flex's C++ API is a bit weird, but it's usable.  I have examples here: https://gitlab.lrde.epita.fr/vcsn/vcsn/raw/24c06678d610c90aa158d3368fbb366d159bce8a/lib/vcsn/rat/scan.ll.

Comment: @akim: i'm sure it is *usable* but i'm not particularly interested in using it because the reentrant c api works perfectly for me for both languages. Mastering wierd APIs is no longer a personal goal :-)

Comment: I strongly agree with that!  But I wanted to sit my scanners over C++ streams :)  So I was doomed to use Flex in C++, and it was _okay_.  On the positive side, it provided me with a proper means to have scanner persistent variables (distinct between scanners) by adding them to the scanner objects.  This requires tailoring `FlexLexer.hh` though.